# How does case sensitivity work github packages and scope (npm.pkg.github.com)

Tags: github, npm

I am trying to get set up using github packages (npm.pkg.github.com), but have a few questions:

1. It seems like the best way to access my orgs packages repository is to use a 'personal access token', which I have now set up and then put in a ~/.npmrc file with the following: `//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=TOKEN` line.  Is this correct for authentication and is this the 'preferred' way?
2. It seems that you can specify which package repository to use and switch it to github packages with the following .npmrc file in your project root: `registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`.
   Supposedly when you install like this, it will go through github to fetch packages and github will in turn fetch packages from npm if needed.  Is this information correct?
3. I tried exactly this, but npm install just gave me a bunch of 404 errors.  What Could I be doing wrong?
4. My organisation has a github account and it sounds like I can use that name (or any user accounts name I have access and permissions to) as my scope for my packages.  But I also hear that npm only supports lowercase package names and my org account name has capital letters in it.  Can I still use it as the scope for github packages?
5. Someone suggested that I can fill in my scope name on packages in lower case and it will work and still publish to the right org account, is this true?
6. Also, it was suggested that if I put the scope (org name) in .npmrc: `@myOrg:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com` that I should use the version of the org name that matches the github account (has capital letters).  Is this also true?

Apologies for all the questions, but they're all kind of related and I have had a lot of trouble finding information that's simple enough to parse without existing knowledge and context.

Answer (score 0):

Some messing around, and I think I managed to figure everything out.

1. It seems classic tokens are the preferred way from github. The fine tuned tokens appear to not work at all. Also, having them in an account `.npmrc` file like I have there, did not work for me, I needed to enter it as a password after running: `npm login -registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --auth-type=legacy`. Apparently, you cannot use your github password for this if you have 2fa enabled.
2. Using an `registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com` in `.npmrc` works to set your npm commands against github, but what did not work for me was: `@userName:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`. Don't know why.  Even npm login command will fail like this.
3. The answer is the same as above.  Set the `.npmrc` correctly and make sure to use npm to login to `npm.pkg.github.com` first.

4-6) As for capitals in org/user name.  My testing suggests that it doesn't matter what you put where, capital or lower case. All capitals are automatically converted to lower case and github itself appears to not care about case. So just follow the npm standard and make it all lower case and you're golden.